# height difference between android togglebutton class and togglebutton xml

Tags: android, xml, class, height, togglebutton

So I started looking at extending the ToggleButton so I could in addition to using states in the selector, I wanted to also draw on top of it. As I was going though this I realized that there seems to be an issue with the height and layout_height, which I might be missing something...

tbutton

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/on"/>
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/off"/>
    </selector>
```

now inside the layout xml (snippit of course)

```
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/mytoggle1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/tbutton"
              android:textOn=""
              android:textOff=""
              android:layout_weight="0"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/PADDING"/>

    <edu.ninjacore.components.codeToggle android:id="@+id/mytoggle2"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         android:layout_weight="0"/>
```

in the create of codeToggle I have in the constructor (nothing fancy)

```
    public codeToggle(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tbutton));
    }
```

What you'll find is that the codeToggle will have a different height than the ToggleButton height... it's like there is a slew more padding on the top and bottom.

Why is that, and how would you correct it?

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution was rather simple, as I wasn't going to the right location for width and height.

What you should use is the:

```
    getBackground().getBounds()
```

Doing this it will allow you to resize whatever you want to draw and position based on the constraints of the current item (in this case the ToggleButton)